# How to correctly hide helpers (inner) classes inside a class in C#

Tags: c#, class, class-design

I am having problems understanding how to correctly encapsulate my class. It is (**or should be**) an inmutable class.

I am using a "helper class" and I want it to be not accesible from the outside.

```
namespace MyApp
{

    [Flags]
    public enum OctaveGroups
    {
        None = 0,
        oneOctave = 1
    }

    class Frequencies
    {
        // HelperClass
        public class Frequency
        {
            public string Name { get;  set; }
            public OctaveGroups Octave { get; set; }
        }

        public readonly static List<Frequency> All = new List<Frequency>
        {
        #region Complete Frequencies Data

                new Frequency { Name = "63", Hz = 63,
                    Octave = OctaveGroups.oneOctave | OctaveGroups.None,
                    },

                new Frequency { Name = "80", Hz = 80,
                    Octave = OctaveGroups.None,
                    }
           // And so on..
                //..

        #endregion
        };


        public readonly List<Frequency> OneOctave = All.Where(f => f.Octave.HasFlag(OctaveGroups.oneOctave)).ToList();

        public readonly List<Frequency> None = All.Where(f => f.Octave.HasFlag(OctaveGroups.None)).ToList();

    }
}
```

If I make my `Frequency` class `protected` or `private` I get this error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'List'
>   is less accesible than field 'Frequencies.All'

I get the same error if I make `class Frequency` and `List<Frequency> All`protected and try to make a method that returns a `List<Frequency>` like:

```
public List<Frequency> GetAll()
    {
        return All.Where(f => f.Octave.HasFlag(OctaveGroups.OneOctave)).ToList();
    }
```

How will be the correct way to expose just `.All` `.OneOctave` and `.None` fields while keeping them read only?

Comment: If you want `GetAll` to be public, `Frequency` has to be public. What is the question here? What do you mean by "keeping them read only"? A method that returns stuff, how can that be read only, other than by returning immutable results?

Comment: if you are exposing Frequency you can't make it neither private  nor protected, but if you need immutability you can make property setters internal

Comment: I lost a paragraph in my copy/pasting of code. I want (if it is possible) let my Helper `Class Frequency` to be not accesible because I do not need it in any other place.

Comment: As you code shows (`public readonly List<Frequency> OneOctave =...`) you need `Frequency` in other places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't expect to hide `Frequency` when you are planning in having public methods returning `List<Frequency>`.

Now, what I understand is your issue is that you need accessible property setters in `Frequency` from `Frequencies` but you don't want to expose them to the outside. The way to do this is through an interface that only exposes getters:

```
public interface IFrequency
{
    string Name { get; }
    OctaveGroups Octave { get; }  
}
```

And now, you make `Frequencies.Frequency` a private nested class and you expose only `IFrequency`:

```
class Frequencies
{
    // HelperClass
    private class Frequency: IFrequency
    {
        public string Name { get;  set; }
        public OctaveGroups Octave { get; set; }
    }

    public readonly static List<IFrequency> All = new List<IFrequency>
    {
    #region Complete Frequencies Data

            new Frequency { Name = "63", Hz = 63,
                Octave = OctaveGroups.oneOctave | OctaveGroups.None,
                },

            new Frequency { Name = "80", Hz = 80,
                Octave = OctaveGroups.None,
                }
       // And so on..
            //..

    #endregion
    };


    public readonly List<IFrequency> OneOctave = All.Where(f => f.Octave.HasFlag(OctaveGroups.oneOctave)).ToList();

    public readonly List<IFrequency> None = All.Where(f => f.Octave.HasFlag(OctaveGroups.None)).ToList();

}
```

Now a consumer of `Frequencies` will only see `IFrequency` instances where no setter is exposed and is therefore immutable to the outside world (excluding reflection of course).

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is not to hide them.

You simply cannot **both** hide and expose a class to the outside world, at the same time.

So if you want to declare a public method returning the object, or a collection of the object, you must make the type of the object in question public as well.

Comment: Theres no way to use a inner class just in their parent Class?

Comment: of course there is but not as a return type of public method like you did

Comment: @OlegBogdanov should I create a `dynamic` return or similar? Sorry I come from a Javascript world and I am having a hard time with all this (for me) new types.

Comment: dynamic is absolutely irrelevant here. like the answers says, you can't hide and at the same time return this class to the users, dont you undersatnd the controversity?

Comment: Lets say you have `public List<Frequency>`  and `private class Frequency` What that means? that means you can access to the list from any external source and then you can access `list[0]` and that will give you the frequency. that does not make sense. because now you had frequency as `private` and that should not be accessible from outside of class. that's why compiler doesn't let you do that. @distante

Comment: You can how ever use linq like `All.Where(...).Select(freq => freq.Octave)` and this will give you only octaves. now frequency class can be made private and you only get `Octave` or what ever type you like from frequency. @distante

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary ah! I understand now thanks. I thought in my ignorance that `Frequency` would works just like an "object blueprint" thinking that my return will be just an Object. I think I need to use an Interface.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an internal constructor to your Frequency class.  This will allow you to construct a Frequency from within the class but disallow outside classes from constructing it.  Since it can't be constructed on the outside no one outside of the class will be able to add a new one to your Lists since they are typed to Frequency.

Example:

```
public class ExternalType
    {
        public class InternalType
        {
            internal InternalType(string someString) 
            {
                SomeStringProp = someString;
            }

            public string SomeStringProp { get; private set; }
        }

        public readonly List<InternalType> InternalTypes = new List<InternalType>() 
        {
            new InternalType("test") 
        };
    }
```

If you try to instantiate InternalType outside of ExternalType you will get a compiler error.  However your dependents will be able to read the list.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to add comments to other people's answers yet so posting this here.

If you use the interface method suggested by @InBetween, someone else can also inherit from the IFrequency interface and then be added to the lists on Frequency.

Comment: Upon thinking it through @InBetween's method will work if you make the public lists IEnumerable<Frequency> instead of List<Frequency> because IEnumerable doesn't have an add method.

Comment: You can instantiate `InternalType` outside `ExternalType` (in the same assembly of course).

Comment: Seems you're right @apocalypse.  I don't know how I thought this yesterday.  I just tried my example again and sure enough I can instantiate the InternalType class outside of ExternalType.  I'm going to blame this one on LinqPad ;)